Suggestions on fixing an old deck
The paint on my deck is chipped and I want to repaint it. I'll probably sell the house in 5 years so I think the easiest is to just do some basic sanding or scraping and repaint it.
I think stripping the paint and staining it would be too much work although I heard it can last longer.
Will a belt sander work in removing the chipped paint? Or better yet, how about scraping?


One option might be to pressure wash it.  Anything that the PW doesn't break free should be adhered well enough to paint over.

This isn't chipped paint. It's decaying wood, and the framing below is likely to be much worse. You won't even get five years out of a new coat. IMO it's a waste of money and pollution.

Please ask just one question per post. I removed the request for paint recommendations. It's off topic for several reasons. See the [help].

Agree that the deck is done for. With a 5 year timeline, just fix it properly and enjoy it.

I have had good luck on many occasions when a perfect finish is not required. Get the deck wet with the hose take comet cleanser sprinkle it on the deck and use a wire brush a stiff wire brush to remove any Moss mold mildew scuzz dirt and loose paint. The new paint will go on and stick because the loose paint chips have been removed along with all the other debris. I would not recommend a belt sander it would be much too aggressive and you would have an uneven surface when finished using that tool. Also it would be very time consuming and laborious and Dusty.

I like the wire brush idea. It avoids a lot of dust since I'm not interested in removing all the paint anyway. What is the purpose of the comet cleanser? Is it to remove grease? Is it necessary to "rinse" the deck after using the wire brush to clean the surface prior to painting? Speaking of painting, have you heard of "solid color stains" that seems to last longer than paint yet can cover up the old paint? Thanks

You will have to replace all the rotten boards, scrape the old paint and wood splinters off, set any raised nails, sand it down, thoroughly clean it with a degreaser, or something, to clean the wood so that your new coating will stick and not bubble up in less than a year, then rinse thoroughly with water, allow the deck to completely dry. You could fill in gaps and holes with a sealer then sand it smooth, then after all that you might get away with a new coating, preferable a deck restoration coating, which is much thicker than just paint or stain. A half-baked prep job will give you half-baked and unsatisfactory final results. Good Luck!
